# solving two simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I need to solve these two simultaneous equations and to find $x$ and $y$:

$$\begin{align*}
x^3-x+y&=0\\
y^3-y+x&=0.
\end{align*}$$

I try to make $y=x-x^3$, then substitute to the second equation:

$$(x-x^3)^3-(x-x^3)+x=0,$$

but it seems too hard to factorize. Is this the only way, or is there any other approach? Can someone give me a hint? Either to use substitute or a graph or a  matrix maybe?

The book says the answer is $x=\sqrt2$ and $y=-\sqrt2$ and $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: I wouldn't forget $x = 0$ and $y = 0$...

Comment: Whenever there is no constant term, the solution $0$ is a trivial one. You might remember this useful fact.

Comment: Ah yes!! Thankyou i forgot to write it, i edited my post!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Over the complex numbers $x^3=-y^3$ implies $x=-\omega y$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of $1$ and this leads to two complex-valued solutions in addition to the solutions given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also there is $(0,0)$.

After summing of the both equations we'll get $x^3+y^3=0$, which gives $y=-x$, $x^3-2x=0$, which gives

$x=\sqrt2$ or $x=-\sqrt2$ or $x=0$, which gives the answer:
$$\{(\sqrt2,-\sqrt2), (-\sqrt2,\sqrt2), (0,0)\}.$$

Comment: I got it!! Thankyou so much for answering my question!!!!

Comment: @Devina Muljono You are welcome! By the way, the solution of DuncanH is total  wrong and my solution is true!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is viable, with a little effort:

$$(x-x^3)^3-(x-x^3)+x=x^3(1-x^2)^3+x^3=-x^3((x^2-1)^3-1)=0.$$

$x=0$ is an obvious root, and

$$x^2-1=1,\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}2,\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}2$$
giving
$$x=\pm\sqrt2,\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+i\sqrt3}2},\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-i\sqrt3}2}.$$